# Organizando dados EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Meu objetivo é fazer interpolação Cubic Spline. Para isso estou organizando meus dados da seguinte forma:

[image: Em cada dia (COLUNAS) eu tenho valores para cada data (LINHAS). Na coluna B dia 02/01/2013 tenho 4 valores para 4 datas, por exemplo.]

Fiz uma modificação simples. Calculei os dias uteis entre o dia da coluna B e as datas. Para as datas que não tenho valor não me importo com os dias uteis. Dessa forma, obtive isso:

[image: A interpretação é simples: os dias uteis entre 03/04/2014 e o dia 29/01/2013 é 799]

Para fializar, A minha intenção é fazer uma tabela nesses moldes:

[image]

Ou seja, para o dia (COLUNA!!) 02/01/2013 no vértice (Linha) 858 deve aparecer o valor 23. (Primeira tabela)
para o dia (COLUNA!!) 10/01/2013 no vértice (Linha) 852 deve aparecer o valor 497. (Primeira tabela)
e por aí vai....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoal, ficou confuso? Fiquei o dia inteiro pensando e  avancei até esse ponto. Acho q pode ate ser simples. Se for algo simples é pq o cansaço me venceu. rs

Obrigado

Comment: Acho que sua dúvida se refere a VBA e não a VB, não? Apesar de que talvez nem isso seja necessário..

Comment: Math, perdão vou editar. To pensando em fazer uma procv mas nao ta saindo.

Comment: Onde tem linha 858 e 852 nas suas imagens?

Comment: Adicionei la....

Comment: Aparentemente uma transposição da linha 8 para a coluna B resolve o seu problema, mas isso é feito uma única vez, ou seja, se você atualizar a linha 8 os dados na coluna B não serão atualizados. Isso resolve para você? Ou você precisa de uma fórmula que mantenha essa replicação dos dados em _"tempo real"_?

Comment: Talvez fosse melhor exportar os dados pra CSV e usar uma biblioteca que trabalhar com CSV, ler os dados trabalhar com um vetor e após isto gerar um novo CSV,

Comment: Math, acho q não. Minha matriz objetivo é a terceira. Sendo assim, a coluna B linha a partir da linha 46 só pode ter 4 valores. e essses 4 valores dever estar na linha referente aos vertices:  1 (Linha 46); 316 (Linha361); 818 (Linha 863); 858 (Linha 903).

Comment: Guilherme , vu tentar. Minha habilidade com excel é bem limitada. Mas, ja que é uma saida, vou tentar.

Comment: Confesso que fiquei confuso... se eu puder saber do que se trata, exemplo real, pode facilitar o entendimento. Talvez queira tentar usar 'indice', junto com 'correp' e vincular isso a um 'procv' ou 'proch', dê uma olhada nessas fórmulas aqui <http://excelguru.com.br/excel-2/indice-corresp/> Abs!